# ActiveJob - what's the difference between MyJob.new.perform and MyJob.perform_now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I've found that ActiveJob could triggered by `MyJob.new.perform` and `MyJob.perform_now`.

My question is: what's the difference between these two calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `perform_now` method is a wrapper around the `perform` method of the `ActiveJob::Execution` class. The source code(shortened for answer) for both these methods can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activejob/lib/active_job/execution.rb). The source code is as follows:

```
module ActiveJob
  module Execution
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include ActiveSupport::Rescuable

    # Includes methods for executing and performing jobs instantly.
    module ClassMethods
      # Method 1
      def perform_now(*args)
        job_or_instantiate(*args).perform_now
      end
    end

    # Instance method. Method 2
    def perform_now
      self.executions = (executions || 0) + 1

      deserialize_arguments_if_needed
      run_callbacks :perform do
        perform(*arguments)
      end
    rescue => exception
      rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
    end

    # Method 3
    def perform(*)
      fail NotImplementedError
    end
```

**MyJob.perform_now**
This call, invokes the class method, `perform_now` (Method 1 in the snippet), which internally instantiates an object of `MyJob` and calls the instance method `perform_now` (Method 2 in the snippet). This method deserializes arguments if required, and then runs callbacks that we may have defined in our job file for `MyJob`. After this, it calls the `perform` method(Method 3 in our snippet), which is an instance method of the `ActiveJob::Execution` class.

**MyJob.new.perform**
If we use this notation, we basically instantiate an instance of the job by ourselves, and then call the `perform` method (Method 3 of our snippet) on the job. By doing so, we skip the deserialization provided by `perform_now` and also skip running any callbacks written on our job, `MyJob`.

Illustrated with an example:

```
# app/jobs/my_job.rb

class UpdatePrStatusJob < ApplicationJob
  before_perform do |job|
    p "I'm in the before perform callback"
  end

  def perform(*args)
    p "I'm performing the job"
  end
end
```

`MyJob.perform_now` gives the output:

```
"I'm in the before perform callback"
"I'm performing the job"
```

whereas `MyJob.new.perform` gives the output:

```
"I'm performing the job"
```

[This article by Karol Galanciak](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/09/25/decoding-rails-magic-how-does-activejob-work/) explains jobs in detail and should be an interesting read if you're looking for more information on how jobs work.